# Lua how many variables a "local" can hold?

Tags: variables, lua

I'm currently making a system, since I need to identify too many things as nil or {}, I'm looking for a way like this:

local lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit = {}, {}, {}, {}

I will do it, but how many words I can identify in 1 local?

Comment: What are you doing that requires that many locals? Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why can't you declare 1 variable per line? Are you sure you're not looking for arrays or collections?

Comment: In any case, by empirical testing, you can at most do 200 because at that point the Lua compiler/interpreter will give you an error: **xxx function has more than 200 local variables**. And yes, you can declare all of those 200 variables with 1 local declaration.

Comment: Since you refer to the variables as *words*, perhaps you're looking for an associative array? If so then see [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html#:~:text=An%20associative%20array%20is%20an,want%20to%20a%20table%20dynamically.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds and looks like an X/Y question so my main question back would be **why**, but I'll bite.

You can do at most 200 variables, because by empirical testing, Lua only allows you to have 200 local variables to any piece of code.

**(Note that judging by a comment here, it may seem that the limit is actually supposed to be 256 local variables. This was tested on Lua for Windows. Your mileage may wary apparently.)**

And yes, you can declare and give them all a value using just 1 `local` declaration.

```
local aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,af,ag,ah,ai,aj,ak,al,am,an,ao,ap,aq,ar,as,at,au,av,aw,ax,ay,az,ba,bb,bc,bd,be,bf,bg,bh,bi,bj,bk,bl,bm,bn,bo,bp,bq,br,bs,bt,bu,bv,bw,bx,by,bz,ca,cb,cc,cd,ce,cf,cg,ch,ci,cj,ck,cl,cm,cn,co,cp,cq,cr,cs,ct,cu,cv,cw,cx,cy,cz,da,db,dc,dd,de,df,dg,dh,di,dj,dk,dl,dm,dn,dp,dq,dr,ds,dt,du,dv,dw,dx,dy,dz,ea,eb,ec,ed,ee,ef,eg,eh,ei,ej,ek,el,em,en,eo,ep,eq,er,es,et,eu,ev,ew,ex,ey,ez,fa,fb,fc,fd,fe,ff,fg,fh,fi,fj,fk,fl,fm,fn,fo,fp,fq,fr,fs,ft,fu,fv,fw,fx,fy,fz,ga,gb,gc,gd,ge,gf,gg,gh,gi,gj,gk,gl,gm,gn,go,gp,gq,gr,gs,gt,gu,gv,gw,gx,gy,gz,ha,hb,hc,hd,he,hf,hg,hh,hi,hj,hk,hl,hm,hn,ho,hp,hq,hr,hs=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200
print(aa)
print(ab)
print(ac)
print(ad)
print(ae)
print(af)
print(ag)
print(ah)
print(ai)
print(aj)
print(ak)
print(al)
print(am)
print(an)
print(ao)
print(ap)
print(aq)
print(ar)
print(as)
print(at)
print(au)
print(av)
print(aw)
print(ax)
print(ay)
print(az)
print(ba)
print(bb)
print(bc)
print(bd)
print(be)
print(bf)
print(bg)
print(bh)
print(bi)
print(bj)
print(bk)
print(bl)
print(bm)
print(bn)
print(bo)
print(bp)
print(bq)
print(br)
print(bs)
print(bt)
print(bu)
print(bv)
print(bw)
print(bx)
print(by)
print(bz)
print(ca)
print(cb)
print(cc)
print(cd)
print(ce)
print(cf)
print(cg)
print(ch)
print(ci)
print(cj)
print(ck)
print(cl)
print(cm)
print(cn)
print(co)
print(cp)
print(cq)
print(cr)
print(cs)
print(ct)
print(cu)
print(cv)
print(cw)
print(cx)
print(cy)
print(cz)
print(da)
print(db)
print(dc)
print(dd)
print(de)
print(df)
print(dg)
print(dh)
print(di)
print(dj)
print(dk)
print(dl)
print(dm)
print(dn)
print(dp)
print(dq)
print(dr)
print(ds)
print(dt)
print(du)
print(dv)
print(dw)
print(dx)
print(dy)
print(dz)
print(ea)
print(eb)
print(ec)
print(ed)
print(ee)
print(ef)
print(eg)
print(eh)
print(ei)
print(ej)
print(ek)
print(el)
print(em)
print(en)
print(eo)
print(ep)
print(eq)
print(er)
print(es)
print(et)
print(eu)
print(ev)
print(ew)
print(ex)
print(ey)
print(ez)
print(fa)
print(fb)
print(fc)
print(fd)
print(fe)
print(ff)
print(fg)
print(fh)
print(fi)
print(fj)
print(fk)
print(fl)
print(fm)
print(fn)
print(fo)
print(fp)
print(fq)
print(fr)
print(fs)
print(ft)
print(fu)
print(fv)
print(fw)
print(fx)
print(fy)
print(fz)
print(ga)
print(gb)
print(gc)
print(gd)
print(ge)
print(gf)
print(gg)
print(gh)
print(gi)
print(gj)
print(gk)
print(gl)
print(gm)
print(gn)
print(go)
print(gp)
print(gq)
print(gr)
print(gs)
print(gt)
print(gu)
print(gv)
print(gw)
print(gx)
print(gy)
print(gz)
print(ha)
print(hb)
print(hc)
print(hd)
print(he)
print(hf)
print(hg)
print(hh)
print(hi)
print(hj)
print(hk)
print(hl)
print(hm)
print(hn)
print(ho)
print(hp)
print(hq)
print(hr)
print(hs)
```

Outputs all the numbers from 1 through 200.

Add 1 variable to this, and at least Lua for windows gives this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua.exe: test.lua:1: main function has more than 200 local variables

Comment: Lua's local limit is 256, not 200, because the lua interpreter uses bytes as IDs for locals.

Comment: That might be, but the code still failed at 201.

Comment: Interesting. What version of Lua is this? Were you able to get 256 when you broke it into two chains?

Comment: Lua for windows, version 5.1.5. And no, I added a single line with `local xx = 0` at the end of the above script and it fails with the exact same error message, except for the line number involved. Downloaded and installed from [here](https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows/releases/tag/v5.1.5-52). I notice that lua.org is up to 5.4, but the link on [lua binaries](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/) for Lua for Windows points to this 5.1 version. Perhaps someone needs to update something?

Comment: I've edited your comment information into my answer for now.

Comment: @Mooshua -- the maximum number of local variables per function is hard-coded into the Lua source; it is 200.

Comment: Interesting @adabsurdum. Is there any rationale in the source about why the authors chose 200, and if so, would you mind pointing me in the direction of it? Thanks.

Comment: @Mooshua -- I didn't see a rationale in the comments, other than that the byte code format limits the maximum number; there is a link in my answer to the current source file. Presumably one could change `MAXVARS` for a particular build, so long as it isn't increased beyond 249. I don't know why the authors indicate "must be smaller than 250," though.

Answer (score 3):

Lua has a hard-coded limit which can be found in [lparser.c](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/master/lparser.c) from the Lua source files:

```
/* maximum number of local variables per function (must be smaller
   than 250, due to the bytecode format) */
#define MAXVARS     200
```

That is, any function can have at most 200 local variables declared within it, regardless of how many `local` declarations are used.